# Initiate random class from Class Array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, vue.js, class

I have an array of Classes:

```
possibleEnemies: [
  Slime,
  (i currently have only one)
],
```

and I want to randomly select one of them and store them in a variable like this (they are all derived from the `Enemy` class):

```
this.enemy = new this.possibleEnemies[Math.floor(Math.random()*this.possibleEnemies.length)]()
```

Sadly doing it like that ^ doesn't work and it throws the error that it isn't a constructor:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: this.possibleEnemies[Math.floor(...)] is not a constructor"
```

I have done a lot of searching online on how to do it and couldn't find anything. Could anyone please help me?

Enemy.js

```
export default class Enemy {
    minGold;
    maxGold;
    minMaxHealth;
    maxMaxHealth;

    maxHealth;
    health;

    attackSpeed;
    damage;

    constructor(mig, mag, mimah, mamah, mah, h, ats, dam){
        this.minGold = mig;
        this.maxGold = mag;
        this.minMaxHealth = mimah;
        this.maxMaxHealth = mamah;
        this.maxHealth = mah;
        this.health = h;
        this.attackSpeed = ats;
        this.damage = dam;
    }
}
```

all.js (all enemies in one script)

```
import {default as Enemy} from "./Enemy.js";

export default class Slime extends Enemy {
    constructor() {
        super(
            1,
            3,
            3,
            6,
            6,
            6,
            7,
            8
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems to work fine in the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5wutdoej/. Are you sure `Slime` is being imported correctly? Try `new Slime()` and check if it works properly. Also, don't do everything in a single line. Add a `debugger` above the line. Get the random index and `const randomClass = this.possibleEnemies[randomIndex]` to individual varaibles and verify the values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have missed `length` call on the array:

```
...Math.random()*this.possibleEnemies.length)]
```

#### Note: Modified the answer based on the modified question :)

The following example shows the random creation of an object using plain Javascript. Please check your Vue specific imports and other stuff.

```js
class Slime {
    constructor() {
        console.log('Creating Slime');
    }
    printName() {
        console.log('Slime');
    }
}
class Abc {
    constructor() {
        console.log('Creating Abc');
    }
    printName() {
        console.log('Abc');
    }
}
class Xyz {
    constructor() {
        console.log('Creating Xyz');
    }
    printName() {
        console.log('Xyz');
    }
}
possibleEnemies = [Slime, Abc, Xyz];
let enemy = new possibleEnemies[Math.floor(Math.random() * possibleEnemies.length)]();
console.log("enemy: " + enemy);
enemy.printName();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little refactoring of your code. Since the minimum/maximum health, etc. of a *type* of enemy should probably not be an instance property, I've moved them into a separate `enemyConfigs` mapping, and the base `Enemy` constructor takes care of rolling the stats for each enemy as it's constructed. The neat trick here is that the per-enemy-class configurations are partial; anything you don't define there is taken from the base enemy configuration.

(It's unfortunate that there's apparently no typescript-safe way to override statics in an inheritance hierarchy; otherwise I would've done that instead of a separate mapping per enemy type.)

Oh, and spawning enemies from the list of classes works just fine . . .

```
type MinMax = [number, number];

interface EnemyConfig {
  gold: MinMax;
  health: MinMax;
  attackSpeed: MinMax;
  damage: MinMax;
}

const baseEnemyConfig: EnemyConfig = {
  gold: [0, 0],
  health: [1, 1],
  attackSpeed: [0, 0],
  damage: [0, 0],
};

function initializeNumber([min, max]: MinMax): number {
  return min + Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min));
}

class Enemy {
  public gold: number;
  public health: number;
  public maxHealth: number;
  public attackSpeed: number;
  public damage: number;

  constructor(config?: Partial<EnemyConfig>) {
    const fullConfig = { ...baseEnemyConfig, ...config };
    this.gold = initializeNumber(fullConfig.gold);
    this.health = this.maxHealth = initializeNumber(fullConfig.health);
    this.attackSpeed = initializeNumber(fullConfig.attackSpeed);
    this.damage = initializeNumber(fullConfig.damage);
  }

  public makeNoise(): string {
    return "...";
  }
}

const enemyConfigs: Record<string, Partial<EnemyConfig>> = {
  Goblin: {
    gold: [1, 3],
    health: [3, 6],
    // ... etc
  },
  Titan: {
    gold: [200, 300],
    health: [100, 300],
  },
};

class Goblin extends Enemy {
  constructor() {
    super(enemyConfigs.Goblin);
  }

  public makeNoise() {
    return "Gob!";
  }
}
class Titan extends Enemy {
  constructor() {
    super(enemyConfigs.Titan);
  }

  public makeNoise() {
    return "Titan toot!";
  }
}

const enemyClasses = [Goblin, Titan];

function spawnEnemies(n: number): Array<Enemy> {
  const enemies = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    const cls =
      enemyClasses[Math.floor(Math.random() * enemyClasses.length)];
    const enemy = new cls();
    enemies.push(enemy);
  }
  return enemies;
}

const enemies = spawnEnemies(10);

enemies.forEach((enemy) => {
  console.log(enemy.makeNoise(), enemy.health, enemy.gold);
});
```

This prints out e.g.

```
[LOG]: "Gob!",  3,  2 
[LOG]: "Titan toot!",  208,  246 
[LOG]: "Gob!",  5,  1 
[LOG]: "Titan toot!",  206,  254 
[LOG]: "Gob!",  3,  1 
[LOG]: "Titan toot!",  210,  262 
[LOG]: "Titan toot!",  168,  229 
[LOG]: "Gob!",  5,  2 
[LOG]: "Gob!",  5,  2 
[LOG]: "Titan toot!",  207,  236
```

You can find this on the [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsglgOxgQwB5QLxQNoIK4C2ARhAE4A0U+xZAugNwBQjiwZAZsgMbQCiCEAiADCAewTs4AcygBvRlChTRAGwAmALliIUqJooAWEZCuAGt8JGn1RkwYNwDWAZUgRN2q3oVQ1yAshSEBY61owAvsxc4gDOwFBEyDEQ-IIi4pJSWqlCYhLSmHI+yupa2AAMlOW05D5GJmZlAIyUTTU+dg5cLm4eFVXtin4BQWWVUNW14UyM7HgIXMBw4lCIcEsmcABeEAByhCSkABTYBIiUAai0IV4AlFrUh0WKpBDAeKQIUGdfANSwdgMADp2CpRKJjigzEDSMgEGpRAQjrcoAAqKBHS5QAC030Qt1uTEijC4KiSMSgORAzygYDwRBUcC4SlUHkeZBsdIZTKg9VM5ioBw5Pi5jOZlwAEsZ+Q8haROfSxbZ7E5XBB3LKaPKRYqecNAsFBVqZopogg4qQ8IsIUczZkAPxaAAKyFIGxUAB4qXlMgA+FHyRSm2LxOYqFQ+gpYWRQIFxxLJb0ZaSUONAu0FaY+RRmOAxIElNSFNbu7Z7OVHMMR5NSAuswnZqC5-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-L8Y3Bua8SkltjaKJ1Igbfd2BQsCoLgpCgIwnCCJIii6IE+t5L3UC0P4WYtxg0GAME4UAiXVAOPIjY+NIcDQJ0jEBgdWR0XpSBFVi-dRJRCtnXA4U51XTdSsPSZDaMOrLMQ6QvDcNLMtpCiGB-T4cGqBArOiFIltCJ2CUfl+yKUATQKTj7ZF1uoDbhISQA) too.